# Well-defined multi-variable function

Tags: real-analysis, functions

We all know how to show a single-varible function is well-defined .

If  f:X--->Y by f(x)=y for all x∈ Y.

Then we let x,x'∈X such that
x=x' ==>  f(x)=f(x')

Then f is well-defined.

But I am wondering, if I defined a multi-variable function then how am I gonna show it is well-defined.

Please help me.. Thanks in advance

Comment: Example?  It's the exact same thing.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: A multivariable function such as $f(x,y)$ or a multivalued function?

Comment: Yes. A multi-variable function as f(x,y)